# 720p 60fps playing in slow motion need real time speed?

Tags: playback, slowmotion, framerate

I just got a kodak playsport zx5 and shot some video of a volleyball game at 720p 60fps. I figured since the ball was moving so fast i'd need the 60fps to capture the games clearly. I just downloaded the videos and playing them in KMPlayer and they are in slow motion. How can I get them to play in real time?

Thanks

Comment: what does the OSD info say about the file? Press 'Tab' during playback and the info should pop up on screen. See the line starting with 'Frame'.  And is it playing "smoothish" at half-speed, or is the video stuttering? The former would be a config/file issue whereas the latter is related to the capability of your computer.

Comment: @Mulvya 59.96 fps CPU 30%. It is an older computer I will try playing it on a faster machine with more memory. It's playing kind of smoothish at half speed but occasionally stuttering which I think is my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it plays back in slow-motion is because you recorded it in slow-motion mode. From [Kodak's web page](http://store.kodak.com/store/ekconsus/en_US/pd/ThemeID.3925700/PLAYSPORT_Video_Camera__Zx5/productID.221644700) (my emphasis):

> 720p at 60 fps—for fast action and **super slow motion playback**

Your computer have no problem playing back the video if CPU usage is just 30% and have a full frame rate of 60 fps.

What you need to change this is to re-time your video.

You can do is in many ways - I would suggest a video editor such as Adobe Premier Pro (try their 30 days free trial if you don't have it already), select a project that fits the format (HD720P) but with 30 fps.

Then drop your video on the time line, right-click and select change playback speed (or something in those words). Set 200% or what will suit your video. Render out to final video and the problem will be gone.

Comment: It actually turned out to be my computer. I just played it on another computer Core 2 4gigs of ram 32bit KMplayer and it played perfectly fine.

Comment: I stand corrected. But nothing is better than it actually works :)

Comment: Strange that CPU and Memory wasn't running out even with the file being 3.5 gigs. KMPlayer always played large files perfectly fine. I saw 720p60 video on youtube from the same camera, glad it works.

Comment: I could actually be a disk problem (I forgot this completely in my answer). 720p@60 fps push a raw data-rate at 158 Mb/s, compressed probably 1/3 of that depending on compression. Memory is rarely a problem as the data is buffered to the memory when needed (even with a 5 sec buffer it uses less than 790Mb at any time), but if disk has fragmentation or the disk/interface is slow this can be a problem; explaining the hick-ups as well as the low CPU usage (perhaps you have video support in the video card too that helps the cpu). Perhaps you'll get better result with a defrag on the old computer.